How to create many buttons in GLFW window without additional library
I'm using GLFW library for my GUI app. I need to create some buttons for users to click. From what I learned, GLFW do not have a built in function to add button. So I need to implement it myself.
My first thought was giving each buttons a bounding box, and iterate through all of them. But I'm worrying this to be too slow. How can I optimize it?
struct Button {
    virtual bool IsContained(MousePosition &pos) = 0;
    virtual void DoAction(MouseEvent &e) = 0;
};

class UI {
    std::vector<button *> m_button_vector;
public:
    void DoAction(MouseEvent &e)
    {
        for (auto button_ptr : this->m_button_vector) {
            if (button_ptr->IsContained(e.position)) {
                button_ptr->DoAction(e);
            }
        }
    }

Also I do not want to add additional library in the project.
I try the code I provide above.
I expecting to achieve the same performance as the professional GUI libraries. such as dear imgui, NanoGUI, Qt..
